# enable Alter of constraints in airflow 2.0? Im getting "No support for Alter of constraints in SQLite dialect" when running Airflow initdb

Tags: sqlite, airflow-scheduler, airflow, dialect

Airflow db init command in airflow 2.0

> quote I get the following error- No support for Alter of constraints in SQLite dialect

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the version of SQLite are you using with Airflow 2.0.0. Airflow requires at least 3.15.0 of SQLite

https://github.com/apache/airflow#requirements

Comment: I checked sqlite version . It is 3.7 17

Comment: Can you please upgrade to 3.15.0, and try it out